# Erro na execução de projeto Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Spring (do livreto da Algaworks) e me deparei com o seguinte erro:

> . ____ _ __ _ _ /\ / ' __ _ ()_ __ __ _ \ \ \ \ ( ( )_ | '_ | '| | ' / ` | \ \ \ \ / )| |)| | | | | || (| | ) ) ) ) ' |____| .|| |||
>   |**, | / / / / =========|*|==============|***/=///_/ :: Spring Boot ::
>   (v1.4.0.RELEASE)
>
> 2016-08-03 10:09:27.151 INFO 14480 --- [ restartedMain] b.p.f.festa.GestaoFestaApplication : Starting GestaoFestaApplication
>   on fagner-nbw01 with PID 14480
>   (D:\Dev\workspaces\spring\gestao-festa\target\classes started by
>   Fagner in D:\Dev\workspaces\spring\gestao-festa) 2016-08-03
>   10:09:27.156 INFO 14480 --- [ restartedMain]
>   b.p.f.festa.GestaoFestaApplication : No active profile set, falling
>   back to default profiles: default 2016-08-03 10:09:27.717 INFO 14480
>   --- [ restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@558b3a37:
>   startup date [Wed Aug 03 10:09:27 GMT-03:00 2016]; root of context
>   hierarchy 2016-08-03 10:09:29.920 INFO 14480 --- [ restartedMain]
>   s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with
>   port(s): 8080 (http) 2016-08-03 10:09:29.943 INFO 14480 --- [
>   restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService : Starting
>   service Tomcat 2016-08-03 10:09:29.944 INFO 14480 --- [ restartedMain]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine : Starting Servlet Engine:
>   Apache Tomcat/8.5.4 2016-08-03 10:09:30.149 INFO 14480 ---
>   [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] : Initializing
>   Spring embedded WebApplicationContext 2016-08-03 10:09:30.150 INFO
>   14480 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader : Root
>   WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2439 ms 2016-08-03
>   10:09:30.488 INFO 14480 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean : Mapping servlet:
>   'dispatcherServlet' to [/] 2016-08-03 10:09:30.494 INFO 14480 ---
>   [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping
>   filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/] 2016-08-03 10:09:30.495 INFO
>   14480 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean :
>   Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/] 2016-08-03
>   10:09:30.495 INFO 14480 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter:
>   'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/] 2016-08-03 10:09:30.495 INFO 14480
>   --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/] 2016-08-03 10:09:30.571 WARN
>   14480 --- [ restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext :
>   Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
>   refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'convidadosController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'convidados': No qualifying bean of
>   type [br.pro.fagnerlima.repository.Convidados] found for dependency
>   [br.pro.fagnerlima.repository.Convidados]: expected at least 1 bean
>   which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency
>   annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)};
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [br.pro.fagnerlima.repository.Convidados]
>   found for dependency [br.pro.fagnerlima.repository.Convidados]:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   2016-08-03 10:09:30.575 INFO 14480 --- [ restartedMain]
>   o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService : Stopping service Tomcat
>   2016-08-03 10:09:30.619 INFO 14480 --- [ restartedMain]
>   utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enable debug logging (start with --debug)
>
> 2016-08-03 10:09:30.655 ERROR 14480 --- [ restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'convidadosController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'convidados': No qualifying bean of
>   type [br.pro.fagnerlima.repository.Convidados] found for dependency
>   [br.pro.fagnerlima.repository.Convidados]: expected at least 1 bean
>   which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency
>   annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)};
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [br.pro.fagnerlima.repository.Convidados]
>   found for dependency [br.pro.fagnerlima.repository.Convidados]:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE] at
>   br.pro.fagnerlima.festa.GestaoFestaApplication.main(GestaoFestaApplication.java:10)
>   [classes/:na] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91] at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_91] at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_91] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_91] at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
>   [spring-boot-devtools-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [br.pro.fagnerlima.repository.Convidados]
>   found for dependency [br.pro.fagnerlima.repository.Convidados]:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1406)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1057)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE] ... 24 common frames
>   omitted

Repositório no GitHub: https://github.com/fagnerlima91/primeiros-passos-com-spring

Comment: Tente MOVER* a classe GestaoFestaApplication.java que está no pacote br.pro.fagnerlima.festa para br.pro.fagnerlima. Provavelmente o SpringBoot está olhando apenas as classes que estão no pacote da classe para frente ... Seu repository acabou ficando um diretório acima.

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado.

Comment: vou mover minha sugestão então para resposta e você marca ela como correta ok ?

Comment: Farei isso, @wryel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mova a classe **GestaoFestaApplication.java** que está no pacote **br.pro.fagnerlima.festa** para **br.pro.fagnerlima**. Provavelmente o SpringBoot está olhando apenas as classes que estão no pacote da classe para frente ... Seu repository acabou ficando um diretório acima.